# How to synchronize scatter points and line chart during an update to the data?

Tags: d3.js

I have a slider which adjusts a parameter in a function which generates the data. I am so far able to adjust the line chart correctly when this slider is changed. However, the scatter points seem to be all over the place and I don't know why its doing that.

Is there a way to bind the scatter points to the line chart so that they update in sync?

I'm also not sure whether the exit selection is working properly. Ideally I want the graph to append if the data size increases, and vice versa.

Attached is a minimum working example.

https://jsfiddle.net/jsnewb284/85j6n9ct/

```
chartGroup
  .selectAll(".line-series")
  .data([data])
  .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr('class', 'line-series')
    .attr("d", d => drawLine(d))
    .attr("fill", 'none')
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
    .merge(lines)

chartGroup
  .selectAll(".scatter-points")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr('class', 'scatter-points')
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", d => xScale(d.x))
    .attr("cy", d => yScale(d.y))
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("fill", "black")
    // .merge(scatter)       

lines.attr("d", d => drawLine(d))
scatter.attr("cx", function(d,i){
  let tmp = data[i]
  return xScale(tmp)
}).attr("cy", function(d,i){
  let tmp = data[i]
  return yScale(tmp)
});

lines.exit().remove()
scatter.exit().remove()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Axes**

You update your x-axis and y-axis domains at every slider move, so you should also update the axes.  That is quickly remedied by placing your axis drawing code into a function and calling it when the data changes.

2. **Data Binding with key function**

You were pretty close there. The reason why `scatter.enter()` and `scatter.exit()` were not behaving as you intended, is because by default, d3.js binds the data using the array index as each item's key (i.e. the ID).  That's how it identifies new items to be added, existing items which do not need to be redrawn, and old items to be removed. It works for many cases. But in your case it didn't, because your axes change. So every point, even if they already existed in the data before the change, has to be redrawn at the new x/y scale. One way to tell it to redraw them all, is to set the key to null when binding (`.data(data, d => null)`).  Another way would be to simply select all points, delete and redraw them using `.remove()` and `.append()` without the `enter()`/`exit()` bindings.

*Full example:*

```js
//let sinWave = Math.sin(x)

let range = function(start, stop, step) {
  step = step || 1;
  let arr = []
  for (let i = start; i < stop; i += step) {
    arr.push(i);
  }
  return arr;
}

let generateSinWave = function(x) {
  let y = []
  x.forEach(function(i) {
    y.push(Math.sin(i))
  });
  return y;
}

const generateData = (n) => {
  x = range(0, n, 1)
  y = generateSinWave(x)

  let labels = ['x', 'y']

  let data = []
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    data.push({
      x: x[i],
      y: y[i]
    })
  }
  return data;
}
let margin = {
    top: 50,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 100
  },
  width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right
height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


let xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([0, width])

let yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([height, 0])
  .nice()


let drawLine = d3.line()
  .x(d => xScale(d.x))
  .y(d => yScale(d.y))
//  .curve(d3.curveNatural);


let svg = d3.select('.viz')
  .append('svg')
  .attr("viewBox", `0 0 ${width + margin.left + margin.right} ${height + margin.top + margin.bottom}`)
  .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
  //.attr('width', `${width + margin.left + margin.right}px`)
  //.attr('height', `${height + margin.top + margin.bottom}px`)
  //.classed("svg-content", true);
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'line-chart-container')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);

/* d3.select(".line-chart-container")
          .attr("style", "outline: thin solid black;") 
          .attr("margin-right", "102px") */



const chartGroup = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'line-chart')

// Draw x axis
const xAxisDraw = svg
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'x-axis')
  //.style('font', '14px sans-serif')
  .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height / 2})`);

const yAxisDraw = svg
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'y-axis');

function drawAxis() {
  const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickSizeOuter(0);

  xAxisDraw.call(xAxis);

  const yAxis = d3
    .axisLeft(yScale)
    .ticks(10)
  //.tickSizeInner(-width);

  yAxisDraw.call(yAxis);
}

// x axis label
svg.append('text')
  .attr('class', 'axis-label')
  .attr('text-anchor', 'end')
  .text('X axis')
  .attr('x', width)
  .attr('y', height - margin.bottom + 50)

// y axis label
svg.append('text')
  .attr('class', 'axis-label')
  .attr('text-anchor', 'end')
  .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
  .attr('x', margin.top + 50 - (height / 2))
  .attr('y', margin.left - 160)
  .text('Y axis')

// Draw Header
const header = svg
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'chart-title')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${width / 2 - 75}, ${margin.top - 75})`)
  .append('text')

header.append('tspan').text('Sine wave')

function buildLine(data) {
  xScale.domain([d3.min(data, d => d.x), d3.max(data, d => d.x)])
  yScale.domain([d3.min(data, d => d.y), d3.max(data, d => d.y)])

  drawAxis();

  data = data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b
  })

  let lines = chartGroup.selectAll(".line-series").data([data]);

  let scatter = chartGroup.selectAll(".scatter-points").data(data, d => null);

  lines.enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr('class', 'line-series')
    .attr("d", d => drawLine(d))
    .attr("fill", 'none')
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
    .merge(lines)

  scatter.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr('class', 'scatter-points')
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", d => xScale(d.x))
    .attr("cy", d => yScale(d.y))
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("fill", "black")
  // .merge(scatter)       

  lines.attr("d", d => drawLine(d))
  scatter.attr("cx", function(d, i) {
    let tmp = data[i]
    return xScale(tmp)
  }).attr("cy", function(d, i) {
    let tmp = data[i]
    return yScale(tmp)
  });
  scatter.exit().remove()
  //console.log(data.length)

}

let xRangeSlider = document.getElementById('slider-x-range');
xRangeSlider.min = 10;
xRangeSlider.max = 100;

let data = generateData(xRangeSlider.value)
buildLine(data)

d3.select('#slider-x-range')
  .on("change", d => {
    // d3.selectAll(".scatter-points").data(data).exit().//remove()
    data = generateData(xRangeSlider.value)
    buildLine(data)
  });
```

```css
svg {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.x-axis,
.y-axis {
  font: 16px sans-serif;
}

.axis-label {
  font: 18px sans-serif;
}

.chart-title {
  font: 24px sans-serif;
}

.x-axis .tick:first-of-type text {
  fill: none;
}

.body {
  display: flex;
}

.chart-group-container {
  margin: 10px 20px 20px 20px;
}

.controls-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.controls-header {
  color: black;
  padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
  text-align: left;
}

.controls-body {
  overflow: auto;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  cursor: default;
}

.slidecontainer {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#slider-x-range {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skeleton.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skeleton_override.css">

  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="chart-group-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="controls-container">
        <div class="controls-header">UI Controls</div>
        <div class="controls-body">
          <div class="slider-label">Adjust x axis</div>
          <div class="slidecontainer">
            <span>10</span>
            <input type="range" min="10" max="100" value="1" id="slider-x-range">
            <span>100</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="six columns">
      <div class="chart-container">
        <div class="viz">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```